# "Tерпеть не могут отца и мать" - why not accusative case?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, винительный-падеж

In the sentence "Истории двух девушек, которые поняли, что терпеть не могут отца и мать", why aren't "отца и мать"  in accusative case?

Comment: They **are** in accusative case! :) And the whole phrase is correct.

Comment: Thank you Lara, I was confused. I appreciate your help. Happy New Year! :)  I would like to know how to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Happy New Year to you, too! My answer is in fact a comment, that's why it can't be accepted. So feel free to accept the answer by A K.

Answer (score 8):

Both in accusative already:

a) [отец](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=213627):

[image: отец]

b) [мать](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=156447):

[image]